# Maintain Revision History in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I am learning how PHP/jQuery/MySQL work with each other by creating a web app that maintains a record of my bills and payment made.

I can't wrap my head around on how to structure my database so that I can keep track of payments made. Kinda like a payment history.

I would like to maintain a history of payment amount and the date the payment was made.

Here is my current 'Bills' table.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+
| id | creditor    | amount_owed | monthly_payment | due_date |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+
| 42 | Capital One |      500.00 |           55.00 |       21 |
| 43 | sdf         |       33.00 |           33.00 |       30 |
| 44 | Car Loan    |    15000.00 |          300.00 |       14 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+
```

I was thinking about adding a couple of columns (payment amount/payment date) and duplicating the ids... Anybody of any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new table `bills_payments` with an FK to the `bills` table. That way you can keep track of each paymant made for every bill registry. And plus, you can put interest fees/charges on this table to. It will be like:

```
Bills
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+
| id | creditor    | amount_owed | monthly_payment | due_date |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+
| 42 | Capital One |      500.00 |           55.00 |       21 |
| 43 | sdf         |       33.00 |           33.00 |       30 |
| 44 | Car Loan    |    15000.00 |          300.00 |       14 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+

Bills_payments
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
| idBill | paydValue   | date        | InterestFee | due_date_limit|
+--------+------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| 42     |       55.00 |  2013-11-21 |             |    2013-11-21 |
| 43     |       45.00 |  2013-12-05 |       12.00 |    2013-11-30 |
| 44     |      300.00 |  2013-12-14 |      300.00 |    2013-12-14 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

The due date limit you will have to calculate since you just put the due date on the main table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jorge!